# How to read a data from word document through Oracle Directory and split the document content , insert into a table

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, directory, oracle-apex, plsql-package

I have placed a word document in Oracle Directory. The document contains Headers and paragraphs below the headers. Headers are in Red color and paragraphs below are in black color.

### Eg Document:

Header1 - In Red

This is a paragraph. - In Black

This is a example paragraph. - In Black

Header2 - In Red

This is second approach.

---

I want to read this document and store the content as below.

| Header | Data |
| --- | --- |
| Header1 | This is a paragraph. This is a example paragraph. |
| Header2 | This is second approach. |

Comment: What problem did you encountered while trying to do this? Stackoverflow is not coding free service, we may help you with the errors you have if its not already solved yet in another questions, but you need to show some effort.